# Removing the summary on the order summary page in Woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have a small problem: I would like to know if I can remove the summary on the order summary page, from Woocommerce to save space?

Thank you very much.

Jonathan.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try placing below woocommerce hook in `functions.php` file of your theme.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_review', 'woocommerce_order_review', 10 );
```

Comment: Perfect thank you it works! I would like to know though if I can keep (shipping and total)? Thanks again to you

Comment: If you need to keep some part and remove some then you can also try hiding it via css. If the answer above has helped you then mark it as solution.